# jquery expand nested ul

Tags: jquery, html

i am trying to set active li element based on page

I have html code like this

```
                <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Orders")" class=""><i class="lnr lnr-layers"></i> <span>Orders</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Clients")" class=""><i class="lnr lnr-user"></i> <span>Clients</span></a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#adds" data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed"><i class="lnr lnr-rocket"></i> <span>Adds</span> <i class="icon-submenu lnr lnr-chevron-left"></i></a>
                    <div id="adds" class="collapse ">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Mobile", "Adds")" class="">Mobile</a></li>
                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Push", "Adds")" class="">Push</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

And script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var page = location.pathname;
    if (page == "/admin") {
        var menuItem = $('nav a[href="/admin/dashboard"]');
        menuItem.addClass('active');
    } else {
        var controller = page.split("/")[2];
        var menuItem = $('nav a[href*="' + controller + '"]');
        menuItem.addClass('active');
    }
})
```

But what i can do with nested menu? how to expand it using jquery?
I am tried to use something like `menuItem.parent().parent().toggle()` but it didnt work for me

Comment: Do you use bootstrap framework?

Comment: @Osama Yes, i am using it

Comment: You could programatically add the classes 'open' and 'in' to your #adds div to get the dropdown to display as open?   It might be best to do this with Razor in your view rather than via javascript after page load...

Answer (score 0):

I think bootstrap add class to the div.collapse to do the toggling so try this code I think it will work

```
('.collapse').toggleClass('in');
```

Or

```
menuItem.parent().parent().parent().toggleClass('in');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/).

```
menuItem.closest('.collapse').addClass('active');
```